# Join Different tables from different classes using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have some classes with one or more tables.
How can I join them with criteria?
note:
It's a module and i give tables  dynamically!

Comment: show your code snippet where are you getting error ?

Comment: I need a way for solving my problem.I'm searching for a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there are two tables patient and  patientAddress and you want to join them.Then following is the code snippet:

```
Criteria saleEventCriteria =  getSession().createCriteria(Patient.class)
            .add(Expression.isNotNull("patientAccountNumber"));


Criteria txCriteria = saleEventCriteria.createCriteria("PattientAddress");

List list=txCriteria .list();
```